# View what exactly is the url called when using System.Web.routing in asp.net web forms application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have been using using System.Web.Routing for url routing in global.asax file  code is as below.

```
   public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
   {

       routes.MapPageRoute("Home", "", "~/Home.aspx");


       routes.MapPageRoute("Posts", "Posts/{blog_url}", "~/blog-description.aspx");


   }
   protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       RegisterRoutes( RouteTable.Routes);
   }
```

Comment: Please, explain what you want to do. Perhaps some sample code would help.

Comment: i am getting 404 error ,so unable to get what exactly is the route that is being called.Any way that i can get the route that is being called .Break points are not at all hit in home and blog-description pages.

Comment: Please, update your question, don't ask comments. It's impossible to understand what your problem is. Please, explain what URL you're using, what is the expected result, and what you get. If you're getting a 404 the problem is that your URL isn't being routed at all. Please, give the necesasry information.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are asking, but think you want the route debugging tool, which outputs which route is currently being selected: http://www.allenconway.net/2013/01/route-debugging-in-aspnet-mvc.html